# protractor: can I use expect in the middle of a test?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

So I have quite a complex tests.

Basically it's about a user ordering stuff. She can enter promo codes. I need to test that the first time the promo code can be used, not the second time.

So I had an `expect` after the (long) series of steps required to order, then wanted to continue addin
g a second order and see what happens if she reuses the promocode.

Unfortunately now the test times out.

Couldn't find anything in the protractor docs.

```
...
console.log("final step"); //--< last output
expect(grandTotal.getText()).toBe('' + calc); //--< can I use this expect here, if test flow continues?

browser.sleep(3000).then(function() {
  var placeOrderButton  = element(by.id("place_order"));
  expect(placeOrderButton.getText()).toBe("Order"); //--< and this one?
  placeOrderButton.click();
  console.log("order created");               

  browser.get(config.location+'/#/menu');
```

Comment: yes, you can use expect inbetween tests

Comment: you can, but it's not a good practice.  Those sound like 2 very different test cases, so you should put those in separate `it` blocks.  `it('allows the first promo code', function()...`, then your second one `it('does not allow reused promo code', function()...`.  This way when it fails, you will know which part specifically the test failed on.

Comment: ok thanks for your comments guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add expect anywhere you want, just know that if one fails the test will continue to run, but the result of the test will be failed.
You can see in the console the result of the expects.

A dot (.) means it was a success.

An F means the expect failed.